# How to set null a specific element of an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, null, element

I´m doing a console application that removes an element of an array if a passed number by parameter appears more than one time as element of the array.

I ´ve done the main algorithm but I can´t set null the element. Here is my code:

```
static int[] RemoveElement(ref int[] array, int num)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == num)
        {
            array[i] = 1; //This is a temporal solution.
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Here is the Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = {10, 2, 2, 3, 4};

    Console.WriteLine("Write a number:");
    int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int[] arrayInts = RemoveElement(ref a, b);

    foreach (var variable in arrayInts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(variable);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: If you want to remove elements, use a `List<int>` instead of an array!

Comment: You could use an ArrayList instead. Then you could do `array.remove(i)`

Comment: `int` can not be ``null``

Comment: do you want to remove or to set element to null?

Comment: if null you need to use int? instead of int

Comment: @KevinMee Note: "For a strongly-typed alternative to [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), consider using List<T>"

Comment: You don't need `ref` for how you're using that array. (`ref` is very rarely used in general)

Comment: There is also nullable int (and other types). Declared as int? however you should just use List or orther collection and use its remove method.

Comment: In addition to not needing `ref` you also don't need to return the array from the method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but let me straighten a few things out. This should solve your issue.

1. If you want to set an element in an array to null, make sure the element types of the array are a reference type.

For example: `int` is a value type, and therefore cannot be set to null. You can however use an `object`, or better for integers: use the nullable-int variant: `int?`, and set it to null.

In short, this DOES NOT work:

```
int[] foo = new int[10];
foo[1] = null; // error: int is a value type
```

2. If you want to modify an array, do it in a list; even though you can realloc and copy elements of an array, it's error-prone and probably gives you issues.

So, in code:

```
List<int> foo = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5};
foo.RemoveAt(2);
```

3. If you remove a lot of elements in the middle of a List, you're probably not looking for a List.

There are data structures way more suitable for 'random removal' if that's what you want. For example, linked lists allow you to remove the middle element without moving all data around, and if you need a 'bag of values', use a `HashSet` or a `Dictionary`.

4. And if you still want an array...

It is of course possible, just probably not very efficient:

```
int[] array = new int[10]; //...
Array.Copy(array, src, array, src-1, array.Length - src - 1);
Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length-1);
```

Comment: Note that `int?` is not a reference type.  It's a `struct` that has special treatment when setting and comparing to `null`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Thank you also all the people that commented :D

Comment: @juharr Yes, that's why I mention object, which `box`es the value type. You're right, it's a good addition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to remove repeated elements:

```
var intArray = new[] { 10, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
var remove = intArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Also as others have stated there is no NULL int.

Likewise you can try the same using List

```
List<Type> list1 = list.Distinct().ToList<Type>();
```